# Add text colour to fieldName for Aura <lightning:outputField/>

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, style

I have created an aura component and I would like to change the fieldName to the colour red.
Basically, I want the fieldName "Tip To Smarties" written in Red.

[image]

How can I do that,
Thanks

```
<div class="slds-box slds-theme_default">
   <lightning:outputField fieldName="Tip_To_Smarties__c" />
</div>
```

Comment: did you try adding style like - `<lightning:outputField fieldName="Tip_To_Smarties__c"  style="color:red"/>` or wrapping it in a span adding style it for span

Comment: Hello,
I tried both but still can't manage to change the field color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a class attribute and define you color in the CSS

#### Aura component:

```
<lightning:outputField fieldName="Tip_To_Smarties__c" class="custom-color"/>
```

#### CSS:

```
.THIS .custom-color > * {
   color: red;
}
```

Selecting immediate children this way will target the field label and make **Tip to Smarties** red.